# How to add list into list box on a different form from using a button

Tags: c#, forms, list, listbox

Im trying to add to a listbox in a different form by using a button and a for loop, however it says "Clothes" does not contain a definition for the list box, i have the list box set to public since that's what i found online but has not fixed the problem. Its like its not recognised even when i type Clothes dot and is not there on the drop down menu. I have also tried `F.CustomersList` but this also does not work.

```
private  void LoadCity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)       
{        
    Form F = new Clothes();

    if (F.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _Mexico.Count; i++)
        {
            Clothes.CustomersList.Items.Add(_Mexico.ElementAt(i));
        }
    }             
}
```

Comment: Instance properties and fields (like you listbox) would be on the *instance* of the form, which is `F`, not `Clothes`. But the other problem looks like you're trying to add it *after* the user has dismissed the form. Seems like you should do it before showing the form instead.

Comment: If `F.CustomersList` doesn't work, then please show the code where `CustomersList` is declared in the `Clothes` form.

Comment: @RufusL Thanks for helping, i have tried the F.CustomersList, the error it gives is that form does not contain a definition, the list box is definitely there on the other form. There is not much code on the other form, theres just the CustomerList box

Comment: You said, *"i have the list box set to public"*. Can you show that?

Comment: Add a public method/property in `Clothes` that accepts a `_Mexico` collection. This public method/property will take care of adding the items to the ListBox, so you don't have to expose a Control to the outside world (which may be considered very bad practice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from making no sense to put things in the list after you have closed the form with the list you have to change the initialization from your Form from

```
Form F = new Clothes()
```

to

```
Clothes F = new Clothes()
```

because System.Windows.Forms.Form does not contain your public list. Then you have access to your Listbox through

```
F.CustomersList.Items.Add(_Mexico.ElementAt(i))
```

Just seen that Rufus already mentioned that in his comment, maybe you have to overthink your design.

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept the answer, it would improve your and my reputation.

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to create a List in the Click_Event and set it to the CustomersList Property of the other Form.

```
private Form custForm;

private void LoadCity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{
    if(custForm == null)
    {
        custform = new Clothes(); //Clothes should be a Form
    }
    List cust = new List();
    for(int i = 0; i < _Mexico.Count; i++)
    {
        cust.add(_Mexico.ElementAt(i);
    }
    custform.CustomersList = cust;
}
```

The Property should look like this:

```
private List _CustomersList;
public List CustomersList
{
    get
    {
         return _CustomersList;
    }
    set
    {
        _CustomersList = value;
        //then do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i have just tried this but still get a error on custForm.CustomerList = cust; saying the form does not contain a definition, i have included the property.